# read xml nodes with powershell

Tags: xml, powershell

I need to pick all the nodes from below xml where application name = "secureApps" via powerShell.

I am using below script but receiving error.

```
$xml = [xml](Get-Content AppsConfiguration.xml)

foreach ($node in $xml.SelectNodes('/configurations/application/app')| Where 
$xml.configurations.application.name -eq "SecureApps" ) {

    $app_name = $node.app_name
    $app_path = $node.app_path

    # Create directory if not found
    if(-Not (Test-Path -Path $app_path)) {
    New-Item $app_path -Type Directory
    }

    # Convert directory to virtual directory
    New-WebVirtualDirectory -Site $secure_website_name.website_name -Name 
    $app_name -PhysicalPath $app_path

    $site_path = $secure_iis_site_location + $app_path
    ConvertTo-WebApplication -PSPath $site_path
}
```

The problem is in the line:

```
foreach ($node in $xml.SelectNodes('/configurations/application/app')| Where $xml.configurations.application.name -eq "SecureApps" ) {
```

The XML i am using is as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configurations>
<application name="SecureApps">
    <app id= "1">
        <app_name>atl</app_name>
        <app_path>D:\inetpub\secure\admin\atl</app_path>
    </app>
    <app id= "2">
        <app_name>corporate</app_name>
        <app_path>D:\inetpub\secure\admin\corporate</app_path>
    </app>
    <app id= "3">
        <app_name>f2l</app_name>
        <app_path>D:\inetpub\secure\admin\f2l</app_path>
    </app>
    <app id= "4">
        <app_name>GPModality</app_name>
        <app_path>D:\inetpub\secure\admin\GPModality</app_path>
    </app>
</application>
<application name="webApps">
    <app id= "1">
        <app_name>locations</app_name>
        <app_path>D:\inetpub\web\locations</app_path>
    </app>
</application>
```

Comment: `$xml.SelectNodes('/configurations/application[@name="SecureApps"]/app')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several problems here.

First your `where` condition does not work this way. If you use where without a script block, you have only three parameters: A property name from the current pipeline object, comparison operator and a fixed value.

What you use as first parameter in your where condition is an expression that delivers an object array containing the strings "SecureApps" and "webApps".

PowerShell expects a string containing a property name as first positional parameter of the `where` command, cannot convert the array to such a string and thus fails with an error message.

Trying to correct this error while keeping the simple syntax you would have to find a property in the pipeline object that you can compare against.

Your pipeline object is an "app" XML node, so you could try `ParentNode.Name -eq ...` but dotted properties also don't work with the simple `where` syntax, only plain property names.

So, to fix this particular problem you could fall back to the script block syntax, like this

```
... | Where { $_.ParentNode.Name -eq "SecureApps" }
```

This is not optimal though, because you loop through every `app` node and only then check the parent `application` node. Better to filter for the correct `application` node first and then go through all the app subnodes:

```
foreach ($node in ($xml.configurations.application | Where name -eq "SecureApps").app ) {
```

There is also the possibility that Ansgar mentioned in his comment, to use the fact that .NETs `SelectNodes` uses XPath expressions, so you can use an XPath condition instead of the PowerShell mechanism:

```
foreach ($node in $xml.SelectNodes("/configurations/application[@name='SecureApps']/app")) {
```